# launch errors fail to install

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bpi.mygears"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

this is my manifest feel free to check it and tell me where im wrong i would help a lot if you need to see all i can show you all my project has no error so im having a difficult time finding where im wrong...

Comment: I think you haven't really fixed your activity and manifest, or it would be loading.  Do you have spaces in your directory name?  like having it in c:/program files/gears ?  That could cause the problem.

Comment: i dont have spaces i think i posted my manifest you can check it

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some problems with your naming.  Your package name is "com.bpi.mygears" and you are looking for activities that are com.bpi.gears. Your activities can just be named relative to the package.  It should probably be more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bpi.mygears"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name=".home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Assuming  your stuff is in com.bpi.mygears.  Otherwise, make that first line
`package="com.bpi.gears"` if your stuff is in gears.

Comment: lol its gears only not mygears i did notice that one coz iv been doing this project over and over again thank if an error comes up i hope youll help me thank you

Comment: It would be kind of you to give my answer an "upvote" and "answer" if it helped you. :)

Comment: opss my bad it loaded...sorry but i cant log in ahahahaha

Comment: did you rename your activity names to just have the .MainActivity and .home ?  Also, are you really expecting .MainActivity to run first, or are you expecting .home to run?

Comment: sorry sir i made a mistake it loaded but its ok now...MainActivity runs first its a login activity then home if you login coreectly i didnt notice the launcher coz its logo is not the one i used got to fix it now

Comment: Oh, and getting your project to build and run is often a big hurdle, so hopefully things will go smoothly once you have the "hello world" going.